# Open a cash drawer connected to a usb printer

Tags: linux

I have a cash drawer connected to an Epson TM-T20 connected on a **USB** port.
I have found an example [here](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/30250-printing-5-raw-characters-printer.html) and applied their ideas to with the codes from [here](http://keyhut.com/popopen.htm)  to the printer:

```
echo -en "\033\160\040\025" | lp -d "USB_TM-T20" -o raw
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Since epson provides a java library, I decided to have a look at it and decompiled it.

```
protected byte[] getOpenDrawerCommand()
{
  byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[5];
  if (this.m_objDrawerPort.isSupportRealTimeCommand())
  {
    arrayOfByte[0] = 16;
    arrayOfByte[1] = 20;
    arrayOfByte[2] = 1;
    arrayOfByte[3] = (byte)this.m_objDrawerSettings.getPinNumber(); // seems to be 0
    arrayOfByte[4] = (byte)this.m_objDrawerSettings.getOnTime(true); // between 1 and 8
  }
  else
  {
    arrayOfByte[0] = 27;
    arrayOfByte[1] = 112;
    arrayOfByte[2] = (byte)this.m_objDrawerSettings.getPinNumber(); // seems to be 0
    arrayOfByte[3] = (byte)this.m_objDrawerSettings.getOnTime(false); // [1, 255]
    arrayOfByte[4] = (byte)this.m_objDrawerSettings.getOffTime(false); // [1, 255]
  }
  return arrayOfByte;
}
```

We see that the values from the keyfile seem to be correct (at least the first two). Unfortunately I was unable to find the code where it sends the data.
Do you have an idea where I can find more information? The epson website seems to be kind of sparse.

**Edit**:
It turns out that the connection cable was damaged and the new cable needed to be repinned in order to connect to the printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the man page, `bash`'s `echo` command, as well as standalone `echo`, requires octal character constants to start with a leading zero.  This differs slightly from C.

So, try

```
echo -en '\033\0160\040\025'
```

or just use hexadecimal.

It also looks like you're sending 4 bytes, while the Java snippet indicates that 5 are necessary.

Comment: Yes, I observed this too. But I've also observed that the printer driver somehow doesn't like my raw commands:
"/usr/lib/cups/backend/epsontm failed"
I'll try to fix this first before I make more tests.

Comment: Turns out the wrong ppd was installed. I replaced it with a different one. This however didn't solve the problem. Right now, I'm trying it with windows.

Answer (score 2):

I also have an Epson TM-T20 and found this answer and links to mostly solve my problem, but I checked the manual and found that the code to open the drawer was `ESC p m t1 t2`

This translated to:

```
echo -en '\033p011' | lp -d EPSON_TM_T20 -o raw
```

I used `lpstat -p` to find the correct printer name to use.